# How to add data to asp.net core identity identityDbContext without instantiating it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to add data to database without instantiating identityDbContext. I scaffolded Identity code within asp.net core mvc.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
private readonly courierswiftdcomotnetContext courierswiftdcomotnetContext; // courierswiftdcomotnetContext is derived class from identityDbContext

public void Context(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signinmgr, UserManager<IdentityUser> usrmgr, courierswiftdcomotnetContext _courierswiftdcomotnetContext)
{
var _context = _courierswiftdcomotnet;
var _signInManager = signinmgr;
var _userManager = usrmgr;
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> WriteReview(int Id, string Title, string Description, Enum Category)
{
// courierswiftd.comotnet.Areas.Identity.Data.Reviews is the DbSet<Reviews> Reviews entity of identityDbContext
var x = new courierswiftd.comotnet.Areas.Identity.Data.Reviews();
var title = x.Title;
title = Title;
var description = x.Description;
description = Description;
var category = x.Categoriesj;
category = Category.ToString();

var query = await courierswiftdcomotnetContext.AddRangeAsync(title,description,category);
await courierswiftdcomotnetContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
}
```

I expect the result to be data saved to database by instantiating the Reviews DbSet.
The result is nullreferenceexception on the var x = new courierswiftd.comotnet.Areas.Identity.Data.Reviews();

I have tried var query = new courierswiftdcomotnetContext();
but that gives an exception too saying something about formal parameters or something like that.

Comment: That's not how you use entity framework. You create a context. You don't create DbSets yourself. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/basic

Comment: You need to initialize the members declare as `private readonly ` in constructor with the constructor parameters.. Like `signInManager = signinmgr;`